# How can I get the images outside the table?

Tags: php, html, css

I have a small positioning problem with html and php. I've made a calendar for a school project. Going back and further in time works now! But there is just one problem left: I've used images as control buttons to go back and forth in time with the calendar. It works fine for me, but using my friends laptop, the buttons to control the calendar(going back and forth in time) are IN the table, I think because he uses a different resolution. How can I prevent this? That the buttons are always outside the calendar, no matter the resolution someone uses? Help me out please! Thanks a lot!

Comment: It's a CSS problem. Show us your CSS, or remove auth from that webpage for a moment

Comment: It has to do with the inline css `position: relative;`, together with `left`.

Comment: What do I have to change it into Jeroen?

Comment: Please provide us a static html page (view source in browser and copy paste into a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) for example

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/umujdr9j/

Comment: I just did what u said Jeroen, but when I run it on jsfiddle it isnt like our actual website?

Comment: Hi Anhita, You also should paste the CSS code in the fiddle, [like so](http://jsfiddle.net/umujdr9j/1/) . But first I would suggest you fix other syntax errors inside your HTML. If you wish you can e-mail me for help but I guess Stackoverflow can't be used for personal messages.

Comment: Jeroen, I already have fixed this problem, but thanks a lot! I'm thankful for your kindness!

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to add one extra table row, split it into half and put those buttons inside it. It will be a much cleaner solution than setting a pixel offsets.

There are also some other solutions but this is the easiest one.